# Sufficient condition for infinite product being $>0$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> When is $\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}k^{-\alpha}\right)^{1/2}+\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}k^{-\alpha}\right)^{1/2}}{2^{1/2}}>0$, for $\alpha >0$?

---

Since $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}k^{-\alpha}$ converges to $\frac{1}{2}$ as $k\to\infty$, the fraction $\frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}k^{-\alpha}\right)^{1/2}+\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}k^{-\alpha}\right)^{1/2}}{2^{1/2}}$ converges to $1$ but I'm having serious trouble with the infinite product. How exactly do I use this observation to find sufficient conditions for $\alpha>0$?

Comment: In general, if $a_n\neq-1$ for all  $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\prod^\infty_{n=1}(1+|a_n|)$ converges, then $\prod^\infty_{n=1}(1+a_n)$ converges to some number $p>0$. (The $a_n$ could also be complex numbers).

Comment: @OliverDiaz Thanks but now I obtain $a_k=-1+\frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}k^{-\alpha}\right)^{1/2}+\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}k^{-\alpha}\right)^{1/2}}{2^{1/2}}=-1+\frac{1}{2}\left( \sqrt{1-k^{-\alpha}}+\sqrt{1+k^{-\alpha}} \right)$, the convergence of which (or of the product, rather) doesn't really look obvious to me. Am I maybe missing something?

Comment: Expand each of $\sqrt {1\pm k^{-\alpha}}$ as a power series by the Generalized Binomial Theorem, with an estimate for the sum of the terms in $(\pm k^{-\alpha})^n$ for $n\ge 3.$ Now use the lemma that  if $0\le x_n<1$ for all $n $ then $\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}(1-x_n)>0 \iff \sum_{n\in\Bbb N}x_n<\infty.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the logarithm, you see that the product is $>0$ if and only if
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\log\left(\frac{\sqrt{1-k^{-\alpha}}+\sqrt{1+k^{-\alpha}}}{2}\right) $$
converges.
As $k\rightarrow +\infty$,
$$ \begin{aligned} \log\left(\frac{\sqrt{1-k^{-\alpha}}+\sqrt{1+k^{-\alpha}}}{2}\right) &= \log\left(1+\frac{1}{2k^{2\alpha}}+o\left(\frac{1}{k^{2\alpha}}\right)\right)\sim\frac{1}{2k^{2\alpha}}
\end{aligned} $$
Therefore the sum converges if and only if $\alpha>\frac{1}{2}$, which means that the product is $>0$ if and only if $\alpha>\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I assume you mean $\sqrt{2}$ instead of $2$ in the denominator?

Comment: No, I multiplied by $\sqrt{2}$ on the numerator and the denominator.

Comment: Oh yes, my bad.